# Is there a commonly accepted gender neutral convention to replace the abbreviation EQM (Equivalent Manpower)?

Tags: management, terminology

My organization is seeking to replace all "manpower" terminology with gender neutral terms. There are some instances where the conventional abbreviation "EQM", which stands for "Equivalent Manpower" is used. Is there a commonly accepted substitute for this abbreviation which is gender neutral?

---

**NOTE:** This is **not** a question seeking general answers for terms, and it is thus not a purely opinion based question. This is a question of standards and conventions. If I asked if there is a conventional term in physics for "influence which tends to change the motion of an object" that is not an EL&U question. EL&U could have many answers for a word which means "influence which tends to change the motion of an object", but in physics there is one standard: "Force".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about issues of [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. This isn't about the specifics of English Language.

Comment: @gnat I am asking for a term which is commonly accepted in management. I thought Workplace would have more information on this than EL&U.

Comment: Isn't the term "manpower" pretty widespread and means men or women. Same for "freshman" e.g. in high school or college. No one thinks it is gender biased.

Comment: Your physics analogy doesn't work. If you thought "Force" was a feminine word, and were asking for an alternative, then you **would** be asking a language question, not a physics one. This is no different. "Manpower", like "Force", **is** the standard, conventional, gender-neutral term. It is more standard than any of the alternatives given here, which are all more ambiguous. If you want to follow conventions and maximize understanding, do so, instead of quibbling over imaginary problems.

Comment: @nmclean **I** can't make the decision to use "Manpower". It is already been decided that it is going away. The best I can do is help pick the next most suitable term, which I have accepted below.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Is there a commonly accepted substitute for this abbreviation which is
>   gender neutral?

My current company (and several others where I have worked) uses the term FTE - Full-time Equivalent. We use that for project planning and staffing.

No gender is stated or implied by that term.

I've heard it used at many companies in my part of the world, but I don't know how to define "commonly accepted substitute" in this context.

Comment: My company also uses FTE.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your insight. I've considered the term "Full-time Equivalent" and its abbreviation, but equivalent workforce might work slightly better for our purposes as FTE and EQM/Equivalent Workforce have slightly different connotations.

Comment: FTE seems to be the norm can you say why EQM is different? and I cant find an real definition online is EQM some single company only jargon?

Comment: @Pepone The formal definition of FTE is the workload of one individual. EQM is the total of the FTE values of all members of a group (such as an organization or a site). [Here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22equivalent+manpower%22&tbm=bks) are some examples of the use of the term "equivalent manpower".

Comment: @called2voyage so just say xx department has 250 FTE

Comment: FTE is used only really in summation (like you say EQM is), so it seems identical to me (and very common in my experience as well).  "My department has 15 FTEs, with a total headcount of 20.  10 of my developers are half time and ten are full time."

Comment: FTE is, in my experience, very widely used in professions like teaching and nursing in the USA. It seems a fine choice.

Comment: To add a viewpoint from a different country - In New Zealand, FTE is common and I would not expect anyone to have an issue with Joe's statement "My department has 15 FTEs, with a total headcount of 20."

Comment: My team decided on FTE. The benefits outweighed the disadvantages.

Answer (score 47):

Well, let's leave aside for the moment that "Manpower" ***IS*** gender-neutral ("Man" meaning Mankind, and not males.  Woman is actually a subset/specialization of Man, if you want to break the language down to brass tacks).

Ref:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woman#Etymology

But, I've seen this ridiculous exercise played out a few times, and in all but one, sanity returned when people realized what "Manpower" actually meant.

Terms I've seen that you may wish to consider:

- Workforce Equivalent - WFE  (Oddly enough, was balked at because it "looked like" Wife)
- Effective Labor Output - ELO
- Equivalent Labor - EQL

In the end, it almost always reverted back to EQM once people understood what the word "Man" actually means.

You're being asked to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: **\*comments removed\*** Remember what [comments are for](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). For extended discussions, [Get a Room (a chat room)](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/get-a-room-a-chat-room).

Comment: I do understand what manpower means - but there is a valid objection to the term contained in your own explanation. 'Man' should technically be replaced by 'Woman', since female is the blueprint for homo sapiens, thus making the female primary, not a 'subset/specialization'; it's the other way around from a biological point of view.

Comment: @Bamboo - biologically, yes.  Linguistically, my point stands.  You are welcome to submit your own answer.

Comment: @WesleyLong. No energy for that fight, because really it should be Womankind! Imagine the uproar...

Comment: Actually - You would be "proper" in usurping Man to mean female, by default.  Then males would need a prefix. "He-Man" would work for me.  All males must now be referred to as "He-Men." :)

Comment: I don't believe this answer's asides on Man address why people object to it.  It's not a misunderstanding that Man only means male.  The gender-offense is that yeah, Man means the whole species and the male can use the same name as typifier.  And then Woman are othered.  Sure, you can say it's gender neutral, but it's also deeply gender correlated, and we understand how words structure our world and our relationships in it.  So looking for terms that don't favor in their distributional attachment to either gender is an important social pursuit.

Answer (score 3):

Unless someone else can bring any other insights to this, I have discovered the term **equivalent workforce**, which seems to have replaced "equivalent manpower" (supported by [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equivalent+manpower%2Cequivalent+workforce&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequivalent%20manpower%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cequivalent%20workforce%3B%2Cc0)).

As suggested by Garrison Neely in the comments, there does not appear to be an abbreviation for "equivalent workforce", but the full term is used instead.

Comment: If you're going to go with Google Ngrams as support, I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that *equivalent labor* has always been more-used than either of those, and as of c.1967 *full-time equivalent* (as suggested in another answer) has far eclipsed all of them. http://bit.ly/YcIiNs